# What is Offchain Call in TransactionSource?

Tags: offchain-worker

What is an Off-Chain Call in this scenario?

> for instance an Off-Chain Worker, or an Off-Chain Call

source: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/runtime/src/transaction_validity.rs#L246

They are the same transactions called by Off-Chain Worker?

Answer (score 1):

As explained here : https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/offchain-operations/
This is the runtime that call an off-chain worker that will return a transaction, that transaction will have a Local TransactionSource. To me "Off-chain Call" does not make sense here. Maybe a legacy in the comment.